# VHDL: input signal timing variations

Tags: vhdl, timing

VHDL newbie here; I am trying to solve a problem with an existing CPLD project (based on a Xilinx XC95144XL). The project in question is an plug-in cartridge for a vintage home computer, adding additional functionality.

The interesting problem is that this cartridge runs fine on the initial version of this home computer but not on a subsequent revision, in which a substantial amount of 74LS logic was replaced by a PLA. No other incompatibility problems exist between the two versions.

I traced the problem down to the following code:

```
PROM: process(CS)
variable newAddr : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
  if falling_edge(CS) then                  -- chip select
    if DBR = '0' and BUS_AX(1) = '1' then   -- databus input, A12 = write
      newAddr := Addr(7 downto 5);          -- get ROM bank
      RSelect <= newAddr;                   -- save ROM bank
      Addr <= Addr(4 downto 0) & BUS_DX;    -- new address
    end if;
end process;
```

The problem lies with the last statement, where the databus byte (BUS_DX) is added to Addr. I have been able to determine this is always 0xFF (databus has +5 V pull-ups). Initially I thought this could be some incompatibility between vintage logic and the CPLD, but I know it has no problem with reading or writing to the databus in other scenarios.

The only other thing I can think of is timing; using DSO and logic analyzer, I can see small timing differences (100 ns) here and there between the two home computer revisions; not much for a vintage platform where timing is defined in uS, but probably significant for a modern-ish CPLD.

My question: Would there a synthesizable approach to let signals stabilize (BUS_DX in the example) before further processing?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify: is `falling_edge(CS)` the beginning of the cycle or the end of the cycle? Usually, these things are asynchronous, and not edge-triggered at all.

Comment: I think Dave Tweed is saying that CS is not a clock or strobe, but rather a level.

Comment: We might be able to provide better advice if you told what processor is being used.  6502, maybe?

Comment: Really appreciate the responses; CS is a chip select signal that, when going low, starts the sequence (in this case constructing an address by placing two consecutive bytes on the databus)

Comment: falling_edge means clocked at the falling_edge. Meantime, "Addr <= Addr(4 downto 0) & BUS_DX" does not make sense, while the bank comes from Addr(7..5), that is conflicting bus width. Again, it does not make sense that BUS_DX is shifted continuously at every CS cycle. And, again, in circle, it does not make sense that the Bank select (RSelect) is coming from Addr, which is a shift register of BUS_DX over CS cycle. You need to reveal more, if you need help.

Comment: I see your point; I should have mentioned that Addr is actually 13bits wide; together with the 3 bits bank selection it forms a 16bits address. Sorry should have mentioned that! Also the combination of CS=0. DBR=0 and BUS_AX(1)=1 is unique, in the sense that it is solely used for updating the address. It does work fine in the initial revision. As I am pretty certain that reading 0xFF from the databus instead of an actual value is the problem this seems a timing problem; the CPLD is too fast and reads the databus before the actual value is stable.